# Is htaccess file absolutely necessary in router framework?

Tags: php, url, url-routing, router

As I understand it, creating an htaccess file creates a scalability concern since every Apache request requires a lookup of things (as I understand it 4 file accesses).

Since I know exactly when my application needs to look up the "retty urls" - is there a way to just bypass having an .httaccess file and somehow look it up via a file access of my own?

Also, I am able to know before-hand, what the pretty url will look like.  How can I do the masking most smoothly?

Here is an example:
I made a test page for all trees:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/trees.php

And my application can know the pretty urls to create.
But I have a single tree.php file here:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/tree.php?tree_id=24

How can I make it take the tree_id (for db lookup) and also look pretty like this: 
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/oak-tree

ps - I am using php

Comment: You can just set the .htaccess rules in the Apache config file.

Comment: The regex handler in Apache is not slower than libpcre in PHP. As alternative you could set up a single ErrorDocument fallback handler (much slower). If other (Apache) options are possible (e.g. DocumentRoot handler script using pathinfo) might be more of a question for http://serverfault.com/ for once. MultiViews and ForceType are certainly also possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be too concerned with the overhead of using an .htaccess file. It won't have much of an effect on your server load.
As for your pretty URL scheme, you can look no further than StackOverflow! Notice the structure of this question's url. It looks like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/[ID]/[QUESTION]
```

The ID as you probably have guessed, is the unique ID given to every question on SO. The question that follows (your equivalent being the tree name) is simply dummy text. Try changing anything after the `/4985258/` and retrying the address. It still sends you to this question. That's because the Mod Rewrite that SO uses ignores everything after the id.

In your case, I would suggest a URL structure like this:

```
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/24/oak-tree
```

Using the following htaccess mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/outdoors/trees/([0-9]+) /outdoors/trees/tree.php?tree_id=$1
```

This will match any URL that had an ID in it and send it off to the tree.php script. It's up to you to add the dummy title text to all your links.

---

**EDIT**
If you are truly concerned about the minute performance hit you'll take with an htaccess file, you can always move all the code from your htaccess files to your VirtualHost declaration and then declare `AllowOverride None` to prevent Apache from searching for htaccess files. You can usually find your virtual hosts in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` in Linux or `C:\apache\conf\vhosts.conf` in Windows.

Comment: he was asking whether he can do url rewriting without .htaccess, not about SOs scheme or which one you suggest.

Comment: @ax As I said in my edit, all htaccess declarations can be moved to your VirtualHosts block to save on performance. The only other option that I see that avoids htaccess or mod_rewrite (that is, besides writing your own server in C or C++) would be to postfix a php file with the pretty URL: /outdoors/trees.php/24/oak-tree. I personally don't find these URL's attractive, so I didn't mention them in my post.

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't quite make any effect.  Should I restart Apache?  Also, the .htaccess file lives in the root directory of comehike.com - correct?  Like the same dir as index.php might live? Thanks!!

Comment: If you place your Rewrites in an Apache config file (usually having the .conf extension), yes you will have to `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` Apache. If you haven't, make sure that the scope of your htaccess file is right. You mentioned your htaccess file being in the WWW root, so the code should be right. I'll do some tests, but I'm pretty sure it should be working!

Comment: @PhpMyCoder see @mario's comment to the question for alternative ways to mod_rewrite.

Comment: @ax Not sure what a DocumentRoot handler script is, but it sounds awfully complex for something that can be done with a simple rewrite! :D

Answer (score 1):

to make *any* pretty url (like http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/oak-tree), you have to tell apache what part of that url is your script (without `*.php` in it, how should apache know). "*you have to tell apache*" meaning you have to change the apache configuration - no way around this. you can do that via `.htaccess` (with the performance penalty you mention) or [elsewhere](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html).

what you *can* do to minimize changing the apache config is to set up just one main router (eg. http://www.comehike.com/outdoors) and let it handle all paths below it.

Comment: Ah yes, that is what I need - to set up the router for only the subdirectories of the outdoors directory.  So should I just move the .htaccess file to the outdoors directory and that will do the trick?

Comment: move the .htaccess to the outdoors directory, set up the right rewrite rule so that your php router script in that directory handles everything below http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/, and adapt the router script to handle all paths it gets (`trees/oak-tree` etc.).

Comment: "move the .htaccess to the outdoors directory": that is if you only want http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/* to be pretty url. if you want your whole site pretty url, move it to the root dir of your site (where index.php is your router).